# Tips for enterprise level database design

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I work with an enterprise application and have picked up some tips for DB design

1. All tables should have the following fields that helps in audit trail - 
   `LastChangedBy`, `LastChanged`, `LastChangedPage`
2. All your stored procedures that have dynamic SQL should have the @`bDebug` parameter. By default it's set to 0. If it's set to 1, print out the dynamic SQL statement and this will be really helpful in debugging.
3. For CRUD SPs, have a way of partially updating the table. If your table has 10 fields and in one of the SP, you care about updating only 5 fields, have a layer of abstraction to do this.

Any other useful tips you can think of?

**EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. I am still looking for an answer that can provide a link to tips/tricks/strategies for DB Design.**

Answer (score 4):

For #1: Move to SQL Server 2008 and just turn on Change Data Capture.  If you really need to keep detailed audit trails, this feature alone will justify the cost.

For #2: Any stored procedure with dynamic sql should automatically be put on double secret probation (ie: it's allowed, but has to go through multiple levels of code review to make sure there's not a better way to do it).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the power of the web, its better never to delete anything.  Therefore having a deletedOn date that you can just exclude those objects which have been "deleted" from your searches.  This also helps frantic customers who accidently deleted their account.  Obviously this shouldn't be used in every field.

Comment: HAving an ignore this row field on databases can make many things easier.  I've found most solutions need a "dont use again" style flag so that old data can be searched, but new entries can't reuse the old ID etc.

Comment: For performance reasons, on large scale platforms you may want to take this even further by implementing table partitioning to split you live and delete data. You could also consider implementing an archive database.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts that immediately spring to mind when working with very large database (VLDB):

**Should you implement table partitioning?**

Large database tables, with millions of records, may benefit from table partitioning.

- The availability of this SQL Server
  Feature is restricted to using the
  Enterprise Edition.
- The applicability is dependent on
  your platform hardware and the
  availability of an appropriate
  partitioning key within the table data.

**What are my most frequently accessed tables?**

Consider separation by Filegroup i.e. place Customer table on one Filegroup and Transaction table on another. This permits SQL Server to create multiple threads for file access creating the possibility of sequential I/O.

Then subsequently consider the underlying physical disk structure, i.e. a separate LUN for each Filegroup.

**Devise a Flexible Indexing Strategy**

You will no doubt already have an indexing strategy in mind however for VLDB platforms this should be frequently reviewed. As data volumes increase and data distribution changes so to may the execution plans for your data access queries. You should plan for the need to regularly review your indexing strategy.

Answer (score 1):

LastChangedBy etc. fields are pretty useless. If you really need an audit trail, you need separate audit tables that detail the changes and maintain an audit history. If you don't need an audit trail, the LastChangedBy etc. fields are just added work for no business value.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion one would require **CreatedBy** and **Created** fields.

Comment: @rafek - In our app, we store the CreatedBy as the LastChangedBy and same with the created field as well.

Comment: Then, after update on that record, you don't have information about original creator of it.

Answer (score 0):

Dates should be stored in Utc format and converted to local time at the client.